# net.sf.saxon.om.NamePool$NamePoolLimitException

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui, soap-client, webservice-client

I am calling the third party web service using the SOAP request in my java application. SOAP request is having 2000 patient records to get their updates. While calling to the web service I am getting runtime uncaught exception net.sf.saxon.om.NamePool$NamePoolLimitException: NamePool limit exceeded: max 1023 prefixes per URI. An internal error occurred in the ESB. I want to know 1. Is this client side issue or server side. 2. If this is client side issue how to resolve this problem. Please suggest ASAP as I am facing this issue in my production environment.Thanks

Comment: "ASAP" is not a recommended approach to getting answers to your question

Comment: Sure.My apology.Thanks for letting me know.